# Postfix - Can't Receive External Mail

Tags: email, postfix

i am using webmin control panel with postfix mail server and every thing working well i mean email message is encrypted and mail sending from my server to other companies like gmail also working very good but when some on try to send mail from externally i mean from any other company like gmail i did not receive emails on my admin@mydomain.com . but internally email receiving also working. i am using cloudflare service but i have fully configured my cloudflare dns records MX, A records . but still the problem alive. below is my server postfix main.cf file code

```
> smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes smtp_header_checks =
> pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
> # Global Postfix configuration file. This file lists only a subset
> # of all parameters. For the syntax, and for a complete parameter
> # list, see the postconf(5) manual page (command: "man 5 postconf").
> #
> # For common configuration examples, see BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README
> # and STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README. To find these documents, use
> # the command "postconf html_directory readme_directory", or go to
> # http://www.postfix.org/.
> #
> # For best results, change no more than 2-3 parameters at a time,
> # and test if Postfix still works after every change.
> 
> # SOFT BOUNCE
> #
> # The soft_bounce parameter provides a limited safety net for
> # testing.  When soft_bounce is enabled, mail will remain queued that
> # would otherwise bounce. This parameter disables locally-generated
> # bounces, and prevents the SMTP server from rejecting mail permanently
> # (by changing 5xx replies into 4xx replies). However, soft_bounce
> # is no cure for address rewriting mistakes or mail routing mistakes.
> #
> #soft_bounce = no
> 
> # LOCAL PATHNAME INFORMATION
> #
> # The queue_directory specifies the location of the Postfix queue.
> # This is also the root directory of Postfix daemons that run chrooted.
> # See the files in examples/chroot-setup for setting up Postfix chroot
> # environments on different UNIX systems.
> #
> 
> # The command_directory parameter specifies the location of all
> # postXXX commands.
> # command_directory = /usr/sbin
> 
> # The daemon_directory parameter specifies the location of all Postfix
> # daemon programs (i.e. programs listed in the master.cf file). This
> # directory must be owned by root.
> # daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
> 
> # The data_directory parameter specifies the location of Postfix-writable
> # data files (caches, random numbers). This directory must be owned
> # by the mail_owner account (see below).
> # data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
> 
> # QUEUE AND PROCESS OWNERSHIP
> #
> # The mail_owner parameter specifies the owner of the Postfix queue
> # and of most Postfix daemon processes.  Specify the name of a user
> # account THAT DOES NOT SHARE ITS USER OR GROUP ID WITH OTHER ACCOUNTS
> # AND THAT OWNS NO OTHER FILES OR PROCESSES ON THE SYSTEM.  In
> # particular, don't specify nobody or daemon. PLEASE USE A DEDICATED
> # USER.
> #
> 
> # The default_privs parameter specifies the default rights used by
> # the local delivery agent for delivery to external file or command.
> # These rights are used in the absence of a recipient user context.
> # DO NOT SPECIFY A PRIVILEGED USER OR THE POSTFIX OWNER.
> #
> #default_privs = nobody
> 
> # INTERNET HOST AND DOMAIN NAMES
> # 
> # The myhostname parameter specifies the internet hostname of this
> # mail system. The default is to use the fully-qualified domain name
> # from gethostname(). $myhostname is used as a default value for many
> # other configuration parameters.
> #
> #myhostname = host.domain.tld
> #myhostname = virtual.domain.tld
> 
> # The mydomain parameter specifies the local internet domain name.
> # The default is to use $myhostname minus the first component.
> # $mydomain is used as a default value for many other configuration
> # parameters.
> #
> #mydomain = domain.tld
> 
> # SENDING MAIL
> # 
> # The myorigin parameter specifies the domain that locally-posted
> # mail appears to come from. The default is to append $myhostname,
> # which is fine for small sites.  If you run a domain with multiple
> # machines, you should (1) change this to $mydomain and (2) set up
> # a domain-wide alias database that aliases each user to
> # user@that.users.mailhost.
> #
> # For the sake of consistency between sender and recipient addresses,
> # myorigin also specifies the default domain name that is appended
> # to recipient addresses that have no @domain part.
> #
> #myorigin = $myhostname
> #myorigin = $mydomain
> 
> # RECEIVING MAIL
> 
> # The inet_interfaces parameter specifies the network interface
> # addresses that this mail system receives mail on.  By default,
> # the software claims all active interfaces on the machine. The
> # parameter also controls delivery of mail to user@[ip.address].
> #
> # See also the proxy_interfaces parameter, for network addresses that
> # are forwarded to us via a proxy or network address translator.
> #
> # Note: you need to stop/start Postfix when this parameter changes.
> # inet_interfaces = all
> #inet_interfaces = $myhostname
> #inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
> 
> # Enable IPv4, and IPv6 if supported inet_protocols = all
> 
> # The proxy_interfaces parameter specifies the network interface
> # addresses that this mail system receives mail on by way of a
> # proxy or network address translation unit. This setting extends
> # the address list specified with the inet_interfaces parameter.
> #
> # You must specify your proxy/NAT addresses when your system is a
> # backup MX host for other domains, otherwise mail delivery loops
> # will happen when the primary MX host is down.
> #
> #proxy_interfaces =
> #proxy_interfaces = 1.2.3.4
> 
> # The mydestination parameter specifies the list of domains that this
> # machine considers itself the final destination for.
> #
> # These domains are routed to the delivery agent specified with the
> # local_transport parameter setting. By default, that is the UNIX
> # compatible delivery agent that lookups all recipients in /etc/passwd
> # and /etc/aliases or their equivalent.
> #
> # The default is $myhostname + localhost.$mydomain.  On a mail domain
> # gateway, you should also include $mydomain.
> #
> # Do not specify the names of virtual domains - those domains are
> # specified elsewhere (see VIRTUAL_README).
> #
> # Do not specify the names of domains that this machine is backup MX
> # host for. Specify those names via the relay_domains settings for
> # the SMTP server, or use permit_mx_backup if you are lazy (see
> # STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README).
> #
> # The local machine is always the final destination for mail addressed
> # to user@[the.net.work.address] of an interface that the mail system
> # receives mail on (see the inet_interfaces parameter).
> #
> # Specify a list of host or domain names, /file/name or type:table
> # patterns, separated by commas and/or whitespace. A /file/name
> # pattern is replaced by its contents; a type:table is matched when
> # a name matches a lookup key (the right-hand side is ignored).
> # Continue long lines by starting the next line with whitespace.
> #
> # See also below, section "REJECTING MAIL FOR UNKNOWN LOCAL USERS".
> #
> #mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
> #mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
> #   mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
> 
> # REJECTING MAIL FOR UNKNOWN LOCAL USERS
> #
> # The local_recipient_maps parameter specifies optional lookup tables
> # with all names or addresses of users that are local with respect
> # to $mydestination, $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces.
> #
> # If this parameter is defined, then the SMTP server will reject
> # mail for unknown local users. This parameter is defined by default.
> #
> # To turn off local recipient checking in the SMTP server, specify
> # local_recipient_maps = (i.e. empty).
> #
> # The default setting assumes that you use the default Postfix local
> # delivery agent for local delivery. You need to update the
> # local_recipient_maps setting if:
> #
> # - You define $mydestination domain recipients in files other than
> #   /etc/passwd, /etc/aliases, or the $virtual_alias_maps files.
> #   For example, you define $mydestination domain recipients in    
> #   the $virtual_mailbox_maps files.
> #
> # - You redefine the local delivery agent in master.cf.
> #
> # - You redefine the "local_transport" setting in main.cf.
> #
> # - You use the "luser_relay", "mailbox_transport", or "fallback_transport"
> #   feature of the Postfix local delivery agent (see local(8)).
> #
> # Details are described in the LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README file.
> #
> # Beware: if the Postfix SMTP server runs chrooted, you probably have
> # to access the passwd file via the proxymap service, in order to
> # overcome chroot restrictions. The alternative, having a copy of
> # the system passwd file in the chroot jail is just not practical.
> #
> # The right-hand side of the lookup tables is conveniently ignored.
> # In the left-hand side, specify a bare username, an @domain.tld
> # wild-card, or specify a user@domain.tld address.
> # 
> #local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
> #local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
> #local_recipient_maps =
> 
> # The unknown_local_recipient_reject_code specifies the SMTP server
> # response code when a recipient domain matches $mydestination or
> # ${proxy,inet}_interfaces, while $local_recipient_maps is non-empty
> # and the recipient address or address local-part is not found.
> #
> # The default setting is 550 (reject mail) but it is safer to start
> # with 450 (try again later) until you are certain that your
> # local_recipient_maps settings are OK.
> # unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
> 
> # TRUST AND RELAY CONTROL
> 
> # The mynetworks parameter specifies the list of "trusted" SMTP
> # clients that have more privileges than "strangers".
> #
> # In particular, "trusted" SMTP clients are allowed to relay mail
> # through Postfix.  See the smtpd_recipient_restrictions parameter
> # in postconf(5).
> #
> # You can specify the list of "trusted" network addresses by hand
> # or you can let Postfix do it for you (which is the default).
> #
> # By default (mynetworks_style = subnet), Postfix "trusts" SMTP
> # clients in the same IP subnetworks as the local machine.
> # On Linux, this does works correctly only with interfaces specified
> # with the "ifconfig" command.
> # 
> # Specify "mynetworks_style = class" when Postfix should "trust" SMTP
> # clients in the same IP class A/B/C networks as the local machine.
> # Don't do this with a dialup site - it would cause Postfix to "trust"
> # your entire provider's network.  Instead, specify an explicit
> # mynetworks list by hand, as described below.
> #  
> # Specify "mynetworks_style = host" when Postfix should "trust"
> # only the local machine.
> # 
> #mynetworks_style = class
> #mynetworks_style = subnet
> #mynetworks_style = host
> 
> # Alternatively, you can specify the mynetworks list by hand, in
> # which case Postfix ignores the mynetworks_style setting.
> #
> # Specify an explicit list of network/netmask patterns, where the
> # mask specifies the number of bits in the network part of a host
> # address.
> #
> # You can also specify the absolute pathname of a pattern file instead
> # of listing the patterns here. Specify type:table for table-based lookups
> # (the value on the table right-hand side is not used).
> #
> #mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
> #mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
> #mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/network_table
> 
> # The relay_domains parameter restricts what destinations this system will
> # relay mail to.  See the smtpd_recipient_restrictions description in
> # postconf(5) for detailed information.
> #
> # By default, Postfix relays mail
> # - from "trusted" clients (IP address matches $mynetworks) to any destination,
> # - from "untrusted" clients to destinations that match $relay_domains or
> #   subdomains thereof, except addresses with sender-specified routing.
> # The default relay_domains value is $mydestination.
> # 
> # In addition to the above, the Postfix SMTP server by default accepts mail
> # that Postfix is final destination for:
> # - destinations that match $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces,
> # - destinations that match $mydestination
> # - destinations that match $virtual_alias_domains,
> # - destinations that match $virtual_mailbox_domains.
> # These destinations do not need to be listed in $relay_domains.
> # 
> # Specify a list of hosts or domains, /file/name patterns or type:name
> # lookup tables, separated by commas and/or whitespace.  Continue
> # long lines by starting the next line with whitespace. A file name
> # is replaced by its contents; a type:name table is matched when a
> # (parent) domain appears as lookup key.
> #
> # NOTE: Postfix will not automatically forward mail for domains that
> # list this system as their primary or backup MX host. See the
> # permit_mx_backup restriction description in postconf(5).
> #
> #relay_domains = $mydestination
> 
> # INTERNET OR INTRANET
> 
> # The relayhost parameter specifies the default host to send mail to
> # when no entry is matched in the optional transport(5) table. When
> # no relayhost is given, mail is routed directly to the destination.
> #
> # On an intranet, specify the organizational domain name. If your
> # internal DNS uses no MX records, specify the name of the intranet
> # gateway host instead.
> #
> # In the case of SMTP, specify a domain, host, host:port, [host]:port,
> # [address] or [address]:port; the form [host] turns off MX lookups.
> #
> # If you're connected via UUCP, see also the default_transport parameter.
> #
> #relayhost = $mydomain
> #relayhost = [gateway.my.domain]
> #relayhost = [mailserver.isp.tld]
> #relayhost = uucphost
> #relayhost = [an.ip.add.ress]
> # REJECTING UNKNOWN RELAY USERS
> #
> # The relay_recipient_maps parameter specifies optional lookup tables
> # with all addresses in the domains that match $relay_domains.
> #
> # If this parameter is defined, then the SMTP server will reject
> # mail for unknown relay users. This feature is off by default.
> #
> # The right-hand side of the lookup tables is conveniently ignored.
> # In the left-hand side, specify an @domain.tld wild-card, or specify
> # a user@domain.tld address.
> # 
> #relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
> 
> # INPUT RATE CONTROL
> #
> # The in_flow_delay configuration parameter implements mail input
> # flow control. This feature is turned on by default, although it
> # still needs further development (it's disabled on SCO UNIX due
> # to an SCO bug).
> # 
> # A Postfix process will pause for $in_flow_delay seconds before
> # accepting a new message, when the message arrival rate exceeds the
> # message delivery rate. With the default 100 SMTP server process
> # limit, this limits the mail inflow to 100 messages a second more
> # than the number of messages delivered per second.
> # 
> # Specify 0 to disable the feature. Valid delays are 0..10.
> # 
> #in_flow_delay = 1s
> 
> # ADDRESS REWRITING
> #
> # The ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document gives information about
> # address masquerading or other forms of address rewriting including
> # username->Firstname.Lastname mapping.
> 
> # ADDRESS REDIRECTION (VIRTUAL DOMAIN)
> #
> # The VIRTUAL_README document gives information about the many forms
> # of domain hosting that Postfix supports.
> 
> # "USER HAS MOVED" BOUNCE MESSAGES
> #
> # See the discussion in the ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document.
> 
> # TRANSPORT MAP
> #
> # See the discussion in the ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document.
> 
> # ALIAS DATABASE
> #
> # The alias_maps parameter specifies the list of alias databases used
> # by the local delivery agent. The default list is system dependent.
> #
> # On systems with NIS, the default is to search the local alias
> # database, then the NIS alias database. See aliases(5) for syntax
> # details.
> # 
> # If you change the alias database, run "postalias /etc/aliases" (or
> # wherever your system stores the mail alias file), or simply run
> # "newaliases" to build the necessary DBM or DB file.
> #
> # It will take a minute or so before changes become visible.  Use
> # "postfix reload" to eliminate the delay.
> #
> #alias_maps = dbm:/etc/aliases alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
> #alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
> #alias_maps = netinfo:/aliases
> 
> # The alias_database parameter specifies the alias database(s) that
> # are built with "newaliases" or "sendmail -bi".  This is a separate
> # configuration parameter, because alias_maps (see above) may specify
> # tables that are not necessarily all under control by Postfix.
> #
> #alias_database = dbm:/etc/aliases
> #alias_database = dbm:/etc/mail/aliases alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
> #alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/opt/majordomo/aliases
> 
> # ADDRESS EXTENSIONS (e.g., user+foo)
> #
> # The recipient_delimiter parameter specifies the separator between
> # user names and address extensions (user+foo). See canonical(5),
> # local(8), relocated(5) and virtual(5) for the effects this has on
> # aliases, canonical, virtual, relocated and .forward file lookups.
> # Basically, the software tries user+foo and .forward+foo before
> # trying user and .forward.
> #
> #recipient_delimiter = +
> 
> # DELIVERY TO MAILBOX
> #
> # The home_mailbox parameter specifies the optional pathname of a
> # mailbox file relative to a user's home directory. The default
> # mailbox file is /var/spool/mail/user or /var/mail/user.  Specify
> # "Maildir/" for qmail-style delivery (the / is required).
> #
> #home_mailbox = Mailbox
> #home_mailbox = Maildir/
> 
> # The mail_spool_directory parameter specifies the directory where
> # UNIX-style mailboxes are kept. The default setting depends on the
> # system type.
> #
> #mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
> #mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
> 
> # The mailbox_command parameter specifies the optional external
> # command to use instead of mailbox delivery. The command is run as
> # the recipient with proper HOME, SHELL and LOGNAME environment settings.
> # Exception:  delivery for root is done as $default_user.
> #
> # Other environment variables of interest: USER (recipient username),
> # EXTENSION (address extension), DOMAIN (domain part of address),
> # and LOCAL (the address localpart).
> #
> # Unlike other Postfix configuration parameters, the mailbox_command
> # parameter is not subjected to $parameter substitutions. This is to
> # make it easier to specify shell syntax (see example below).
> #
> # Avoid shell meta characters because they will force Postfix to run
> # an expensive shell process. Procmail alone is expensive enough.
> #
> # IF YOU USE THIS TO DELIVER MAIL SYSTEM-WIDE, YOU MUST SET UP AN
> # ALIAS THAT FORWARDS MAIL FOR ROOT TO A REAL USER.
> #
> #mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail
> #mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
> 
> # The mailbox_transport specifies the optional transport in master.cf
> # to use after processing aliases and .forward files. This parameter
> # has precedence over the mailbox_command, fallback_transport and
> # luser_relay parameters.
> #
> # Specify a string of the form transport:nexthop, where transport is
> # the name of a mail delivery transport defined in master.cf.  The
> # :nexthop part is optional. For more details see the sample transport
> # configuration file.
> #
> # NOTE: if you use this feature for accounts not in the UNIX password
> # file, then you must update the "local_recipient_maps" setting in
> # the main.cf file, otherwise the SMTP server will reject mail for    
> # non-UNIX accounts with "User unknown in local recipient table".
> #
> # Cyrus IMAP over LMTP. Specify ``lmtpunix      cmd="lmtpd"
> # listen="/var/imap/socket/lmtp" prefork=0'' in cyrus.conf.
> #mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
> 
> # If using the cyrus-imapd IMAP server deliver local mail to the IMAP
> # server using LMTP (Local Mail Transport Protocol), this is prefered
> # over the older cyrus deliver program by setting the
> # mailbox_transport as below:
> #
> # mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
> #
> # The efficiency of LMTP delivery for cyrus-imapd can be enhanced via
> # these settings.
> #
> # local_destination_recipient_limit = 300
> # local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
> #
> # Of course you should adjust these settings as appropriate for the
> # capacity of the hardware you are using. The recipient limit setting
> # can be used to take advantage of the single instance message store
> # capability of Cyrus. The concurrency limit can be used to control
> # how many simultaneous LMTP sessions will be permitted to the Cyrus
> # message store. 
> #
> # Cyrus IMAP via command line. Uncomment the "cyrus...pipe" and
> # subsequent line in master.cf.
> #mailbox_transport = cyrus
> 
> # The fallback_transport specifies the optional transport in master.cf
> # to use for recipients that are not found in the UNIX passwd database.
> # This parameter has precedence over the luser_relay parameter.
> #
> # Specify a string of the form transport:nexthop, where transport is
> # the name of a mail delivery transport defined in master.cf.  The
> # :nexthop part is optional. For more details see the sample transport
> # configuration file.
> #
> # NOTE: if you use this feature for accounts not in the UNIX password
> # file, then you must update the "local_recipient_maps" setting in
> # the main.cf file, otherwise the SMTP server will reject mail for    
> # non-UNIX accounts with "User unknown in local recipient table".
> 
> #
> # For details, see "man header_checks".
> #
> #header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
> # FAST ETRN SERVICE
> #
> # Postfix maintains per-destination logfiles with information about
> # deferred mail, so that mail can be flushed quickly with the SMTP
> # "ETRN domain.tld" command, or by executing "sendmail -qRdomain.tld".
> # See the ETRN_README document for a detailed description.
> # 
> # The fast_flush_domains parameter controls what destinations are
> # eligible for this service. By default, they are all domains that
> # this server is willing to relay mail to.
> # 
> #fast_flush_domains = $relay_domains
> 
> # SHOW SOFTWARE VERSION OR NOT
> #
> # The smtpd_banner parameter specifies the text that follows the 220
> # code in the SMTP server's greeting banner. Some people like to see
> # the mail version advertised. By default, Postfix shows no version.
> #
> # You MUST specify $myhostname at the start of the text. That is an
> # RFC requirement. Postfix itself does not care.
> #
> #smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
> #smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name ($mail_version)
> 
> # PARALLEL DELIVERY TO THE SAME DESTINATION
> #
> # How many parallel deliveries to the same user or domain? With local
> # delivery, it does not make sense to do massively parallel delivery
> # to the same user, because mailbox updates must happen sequentially,
> # and expensive pipelines in .forward files can cause disasters when
> # too many are run at the same time. With SMTP deliveries, 10
> # simultaneous connections to the same domain could be sufficient to
> # raise eyebrows.
> # 
> # Each message delivery transport has its XXX_destination_concurrency_limit
> # parameter.  The default is $default_destination_concurrency_limit for
> # most delivery transports. For the local delivery agent the default is 2.
> 
> #local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
> #default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20
> 
> # DEBUGGING CONTROL
> #
> # The debug_peer_level parameter specifies the increment in verbose
> # logging level when an SMTP client or server host name or address
> # matches a pattern in the debug_peer_list parameter.
> # debug_peer_level = 2
> 
> 
> debugger_command =
>      PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
>      ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
> 
> 
> 
> # sample_directory: The location of the Postfix sample configuration files.
> # This parameter is obsolete as of Postfix 2.1.
> # sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
> 
> # readme_directory: The location of the Postfix README files.
> # readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual sender_bcc_maps =
> hash:/etc/postfix/bcc mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o
> -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME home_mailbox = Maildir/ smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit_inet_interfaces
> reject_unknown_client reject_unauth_destination mailbox_size_limit = 0
> allow_percent_hack = no smtpd_use_tls = yes
> 
> smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
> smtpd_delay_reject = no smtp_sasl_password_maps =
> hash:/etc/postfix/smtp_sasl_password_map
> 
> smtpd_tls_security_level = may smtp_tls_security_level = may
> smtp_tls_loglevel = 1 smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1myorigin = $mydomain
> mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
```

Comment: I think you posted the wrong domain name. I don't think you own mydomain.com. What is the real domain name?

Comment: mydomain.com  is example domain real domain name is globalexn.com

Comment: That domain doesn't have an MX record!

Comment: i can't show my real domain try to understand its not allowed by my client. which domain have problem that domain have MX record i have checked it my self

Comment: Did you get any NDR (Non Delivery Report) when you tried sent mail from outside, for e.g. gmail?

Comment: no i did not  get any NDR mail from gmail .

Comment: Changing MX record take time like ~1day, and crop your config to `postconf -n`

Comment: What is the result of an online test for the domain? You can check whole lot of things at: http://mxtoolbox.com.

Comment: issue has been resolved when i turn off TSL from my webmin panel . now mails sending and receiving work well .

Answer (score 0):

issue has been resolved when i turn of TSL from my webmin control panel and now emails sending and receiving function work correctly.

Comment: What does TSL mean? Probably you mean TLS?

Comment: yes it was TLS sorry for words misplaced.

Comment: wow, nice explanation